# How do I let the program "read" and copy the content of a text file?

Tags: python, store

So if I have a program that saves e.g. a number in an external txt. file

```
x = open("example.txt", "w")
x.write(str(100))
x.close
exit
```

How do I access that number if I start the program again?

```
pseudocode

open example.txt
read 100
copy 100
"paste" it in my program (e.g. save it as a var) to use it in my program
```

I hope you get what I am trying to convey. I am sure that there are easier ways to store information from another "session" and if there are I would like to know them too if you don't mind, but I would also appreciate an answer to this question.

Comment: Did you already read this? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean reading the file?

Try something like this:

```py
number = 100

# Save number
with open("example.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(number))

# Retrive number
with open("example.txt", "r") as file:
    number = file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = open("example.txt", "w")
x.write(str(100))
x.close
exit
```

After this

```
x=open("example.txt","r")
num=x.read()
print(num)
x.close
```

Answer (score 0):

I think whatever you want is to read the whole file, check if '100' is in it, if it is then read or else write it:

```
with open('example.txt') a f:
  s=f.read()
if '100' in s:
  print(100)
else:
  with open('example.txt','w') as g:
    g.write('100')
```